# Как правильно заполнить ячейки QTableWidget данными QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qtablewidget

В этом коде в таблице `TableWidget` в первый столбец вставляется `dataEdit`, но почему при запуске кода открывается таблица но, без `dataEdit`.

Как это исправить?

**test_ui_log.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from test_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

Window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(Window)
Window.setFixedSize(320, 240)
Window.show()

def dataEdit():
    pass



row = 3
column = 2
ui.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(row, column)

for row in range(ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
    date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
    date_from.setDateTime(
        #QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 4))
        QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26), QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
    )
    ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)  # !!!

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот .ui: **test_ui.py**

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        if (self.tableWidget.columnCount() < 2):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        if (self.tableWidget.rowCount() < 3):
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(u"tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(130)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f, \u0447\u0430\u0441", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None));
    # retranslateUi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from test_ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        if not MainWindow.objectName():
            MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 240)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        if (self.tableWidget.columnCount() < 2):
            self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        __qtablewidgetitem = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem)
        __qtablewidgetitem1 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem1)
        if (self.tableWidget.rowCount() < 3):
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        __qtablewidgetitem2 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(0, __qtablewidgetitem2)
        __qtablewidgetitem3 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(1, __qtablewidgetitem3)
        __qtablewidgetitem4 = QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderItem(2, __qtablewidgetitem4)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName(u"tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(130)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setObjectName(u"menubar")
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 320, 21))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0421\u0447\u0438\u0442\u0430\u0442\u044c \u0434\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435", None))
        ___qtablewidgetitem = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem1 = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem1.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"\u041e\u0431\u0449\u0435\u0435 \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f, \u0447\u0430\u0441", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem2 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(0)
        ___qtablewidgetitem2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"1", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem3 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)
        ___qtablewidgetitem3.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"2", None));
        ___qtablewidgetitem4 = self.tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(2)
        ___qtablewidgetitem4.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"3", None));


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                #QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 4))
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26), QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
            )
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)  # !!!

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]